# Angular ng-repeat not working with $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngroute

I've tried a long time to solve my problem. The problem is after fetching data by post method my HTML content is not updating. My pages are being changed by `$routeProvider` and the codes is as follows:

```
socialGroup.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/my-groups', {
    templateUrl: 'my-groups.html'
  }).otherwise({ templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' });
});
```

### View

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-groups.html">
  <div data-ng-controller="myGroups" class="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><h1>My Groups</h1></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-hover table-inverse">
        <thead>
          <tr class="success">
            <th>SN</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>Group Name</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>Action</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <tr class="info">
              <th scope="row">{{group.id}}</th>
              <td>
                <a href="#/stays-group/{{group.token}}" class="text-info" title="View {{group.name}} posts.">
                  <b>{{group.name}}</b>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{group.link}}" title="{{group.label}}">
                  <b>{{group.label}}</b>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td title="Group is active">
                <label data-ng-show="group.active" class="text-success" ><b>Active</b></label>
                <label data-ng-hide="group.active" class="text-danger" ><b>Inactive</b></label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

### Controller

```
socialGroup.controller('myGroups', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.groups = [];
  $http({
    method: "post",
    url: 'my-groups-link',
    data: $.param({ token:sha1( Math.random() ) }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).then(function success(response) {
    $scope.groups = response.data;
    //$scope.$apply();
    //$scope.$applyAsync();
    console.log($scope.groups);
  }, function error(response) {});
});
```

I observed my console and showed the data had come from the server but the data is not updating to view.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @Sujithrao I got error when applied `$scope.$apply();` and the error was `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] `

Comment: Please check console $scope.groups is display your result or not ?

Comment: @RonakPatel `response` is OK and was array like `[{id:1,...},{id:2...}]`

Comment: console.log($scope.groups) display your result or not ?

OR try with only ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem but you can't have a `<div>` in `<tr>`

Just loop over your data by using `ng-repeat` on `<tr>`

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="info" data-ng-repeat="group in groups">
```